# How to count lists inside another list List<List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>>

Tags: c#, list, count, nested-lists

Now this is example list :

```
List<List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>> dblWordFreqByCluster = 
    new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>>();
```

What i want is getting the list count at this main list (dblWordFreqByCluster). Which means getting count of `List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>` lists.

I can count them via making foreach iteration which i don't want to because i suppose that would cause unnecessary performance loss.

Comment: using foreach will likely not affect performance. Linq is likely to be slower but more compact. Maybe you can consider wrapping KeyValuePair<string, double> inside a class with a count property as well. It might help cleanup things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple:

```
 List<List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>> dblWordFreqByCluster = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>>();
 int count = dblWordFreqByCluster.count;
```

Should work...

Edited: I thought it was java ;)

Comment: It was working :D I thought it was going to count all of the elements not the lists.

Answer (score 15):

Using LINQ you could do

```
int totalCount = dblWordFreqByCluster.Sum(c => c.Count);
```

However, that isn't much different than using a foreach loop, but it would be less verbose and just as easy to read.